# Change Message on online Event Payment Confirmation Screen

Tags: civievent

We have a payment processor for online payments.

When Someone registers for an event online - a confirmation Screen shows the registration payment has been submitted for processing.  I would like to change the wording on this final screen.

Where can I find this please.

help appreciated - thank you.

Comment: Are you using CiviCRM event registration or webform or caldera form?

Comment: We're using CIVICRM Event Registration through wordpress

Comment: Is it possible to add the confirmation screenshot?

Comment: I use the Drupal version, so it might be slightly different. But when I edit an event, on the "Online Registration" tab there is an area for "Confirmation Screen". Does the WP version not have this? Or do you mean some automated text? That is usually in the templates, which you can create a custom version of that.

Comment: Thanks @JenniSimonis It does have this and I use it but the 'it's gone to our processor still appears from wherever it's set.  I've added other text now from this space, but still not quite there in tidying it up so the text doesn't show.

Comment: Maybe in the template files, then? We've got custom copies of a number of those.